# Using R to add Help Icon beside radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to place a helpful icon on the right side of each radio button. When the user hovers over or clicks the helpful icon, I would want text to appear.

The below image is a dropdown menu, but I'm using radio buttons.

**NOTE:** The radio button options are from a csv file.

[example of what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzA5e.png)

Below is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(5, 
           wellPanel(
             radioButtons('var',
                          h4('Select a Model Object'), 
                          choices = c(""), 
                          width = '37%'
             ),
             shinyDirButton('directory', 'Select Directory', 'Please Select a Directory') 
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Get folder names within the system_models directory
  model_names <- read.csv("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/model_names.csv")
  
  # Update choices for selectInput0
  updateRadioButtons(session, "var", choices = setNames(model_names$original_name, model_names$display_name))
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use the `shinyhelper` package, [here](https://github.com/cwthom/shinyhelper).

Comment: @Limey, thanks for the comment. 
I looked at the library but I'm still confused on how I can use its functions to achieve my desired results. Are you able to help me? I should probably indicate that I'm new to shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way of putting the help icon along side each button in a set of radio buttons because `radioButtons` doesn't give direct access to each individual button.  There will be a way, but it might be complex.  I wonder if it's worth the effort...

It's easy to put a help icon against each entry in a list of checkboxes though.  You can easily monitor the checkboxes to make sure only one is checked at a given time.

I've provided help content for only one of the widgets, but you should be able to work out what you need to do for the rest.

By the way, your sample code was not reproducible.  You'd forgotten to include your `library` calls and, more seriously, we don't have access to your desktop, so we can't populate the radio button list.  So I've done something generic.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyhelper)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      5, 
      wellPanel(
        radioButtons(
          'var',
          h4('Make a choice'), 
          choices = LETTERS[1:4]
        ) %>% 
        helper()
      )
    ),
    column(
      5, 
      wellPanel(
          h4('Make another choice'), 
          checkboxInput("checkboxA", "A") %>% 
            helper(
              type = "inline", 
              title="Help for item A", 
              content = "Blah, blah, blah!"
            ),
          checkboxInput("checkboxB", "B") %>% helper(),
          checkboxInput("checkboxC", "C") %>% helper(),
          checkboxInput("checkboxD", "D") %>% helper()
      )
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe_helpers()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've included the `magrittr` package because I think piping makes the code more readable.  If you don't want to use it, then a sample equivalent is

```
helper(checkboxInput("checkboxB", "B"))
```

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. Although this is very helpful, the code should not hardcode the options for the checkboxes. That's why in the code I pasted, I didn't specify anything for c(""). The reason why I should not hardcode anything and get the choices from the CSV is because it'll make it much easier for people to add additional choices. 
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So I understand. But since you didn’t provide a means to implement your dynamic options, I could either provide static options, or invent a dynamic process. I chose the former because it allowed attention to focus on the subject of your question, which was the provision of help icons, not dynamic UI elements. You can easily adapt what I have done to your actual use case.